# Handle multiple TFS for one solutions

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Currently my  solution connects to Client TFS. We have configured a new TFS server in our organisation. Is it possible to connect the same solution to both TFS servers?

While check in or get latest, I need to have an option to select the TFS server(client TFS or Local TFS) and do the operations with selected TFS. Is it possible?

I am using TFS 2010.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but even if it was, wouldn't it be a better idea to have two separate workspaces? Those could be on different servers. You would decide which server to create your pending changes for (and later check in to) by using the appropriate workspace.

Comment: As long as you're not trying to host the same code in both server (i.e. you want to connect to multiple TFS server which host separate projects).